# Webpack Encore: unexpected SCSS import order

Tags: css, webpack, sass

I use Symfony + Webpack Encore and try to split styles into "layout" and "page-based", but only to make development more comfortable: I still want to compile one css file for them (in fact, there is a limited number of such css files, each one for block of pages, but for easier understanding let's assume only one is necessary). So I do like this:

*_global.scss*

```
// ... bootstrap variables redefenition here

@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

// ... common functions, mixins, font-face definitions here

.my_style1 {
    padding-left: 12px;
    padding-right: 12px;
}

.my_style2 {
    @include make-container-max-widths();
}
```

*app.css*

```
@import "_global"

// other styles here
```

During the compilation (`require('../css/app.scss');` only in my app.js) styles are ordered: [ global, bootstrap, app ] and I don't understand why. I mean, if you use them as:

```
<div class="container my-style1"></div>
```

container's padding will override defined in my-style1.

The most strange thing is that in dev app.css they are ordered as expected (my-style is lower than container), but in prod not (container is lower than my-style). When you work in dev (and Chrome display non-compiled styles, you also see that _grid.scss overrides _global.scss)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for this quick self-answer, I've really spent a lot of time before asking, but after it found the solution quickly. Hope, can save smb's time.

You should simply add other styles to app.js. This way they will recompile on any file change (in previous example they recompile only on app.scss change) and the order will become correct:

*app.js*

```
require('_global.scss');
require('app.scss');
```